# Popover Bootstrap pass delay show and hide values by HTML attributte

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm needing to pass different values delay for show and hide attributes to a popover, and I'm needing an HTML attribute solution. I've tested this code and it works passing an string in data-delay attribute. I'm using Bootstrap 3.

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;" data-toggle="popover" data-delay="1000" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-content="content of my popover>
```

How can I pass different values for show and hide delays using HTML attributes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately setting a delay is a JavaScript thing, which Bootstrap set up with data-delay, but for a custom use such as show/hide, you'd probably have to use JavaScript. Is JavaScript an option for you?

Comment: Yes, I can use Javascript, but I was trying to use HTML attributes, since its only for this popover. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `data-delay` attribute, however this will set both the 'show' and 'hide' time delays. If you wish to set them individually you'll need to [configure the popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#popovers-options). With jQuery you can easily do so:

```js
$(function() {
  // This will enable and configure all popovers present in the page
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    delay: {
      "show": 500,
      "hide": 100
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">click me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is my only chance to get what I want! thank you

Comment: Is it possible to put that object inline? `<a data-delay="show:100;hide:100"></a>`?

Comment: From what I understand that's not possible using HTML attributes, see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#popovers-options).

Comment: Actually that doc you pointed out indicates that delay can be an object, so @Ezequiel Flores you might be able to use `<a data-delay="{"show":100;"hide":100}"></a>` (I haven't tested it, I don't have any projects with Bootstrap right now) Also, if you're satisfied with the above answer, please consider "accepting" it :)

Answer (score 1):

for Bootstrap v5, you can instantiate it like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').forEach(el => {
  if (el.hasAttribute('data-bs-delay-show')) {
    return new Tooltip(el, {
      delay: {
        show: el.getAttribute('data-bs-delay-show'),
        hide: el.getAttribute('data-bs-delay-hide') || 0,
      },
    });
  }
  return new Tooltip(el);
});
```

and then use `data-bs-delay-show` and `data-bs-delay-hide` attributes on the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a number or an object. Therefore, you can specify 'show' and 'hide' delays like this :

```
<span 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    data-delay="{'show':0, 'hide':200}" 
    data-trigger="hover" 
    data-html="true" 
    data-content="content of my popover"
>
    TEST
</span>
```

Comment: this does not work for me in bootstrap3